# Consuming Angular component library modules without consuming all 3rd party packages in that library

Tags: angular, npm

I've been struggling with this and I starting to think it can't be done.

Our team developed a angular component library which uses @angular/material and date-fns for some modules but not for all. Another team in our company would like to use specific modules of the component library which don't use @angular/material and date-fns without including @angular/material and date-fns in their project.

Is this even possible? I can't seem to get it to work.
Tree shaking is only done when buildOptimizer and optimization is set to true so for development this wouldn't work.

Comment: Sadly it's not possible. This problem has been going for years and it doesn't seems to have a fix soon. Every dependencies that a library has needs to be included in the root project as well.

Comment: If your library  has @angular/material as a dependency, then any project using that library will have to install @angular/material aswell. You could make another library with only the modules that aren't dependent on those packages and have your colleagues include that instead.

Comment: @MikeS thanks for the quick reply. It's what I feared. 
Have nice day!

Comment: @JacopoSciampi thanks for the quick reply, It's what I feared. Have a nice day.